# Regular expression to match last item without delimiter

Tags: regex

I have a string of names like this "J. Smith; B. Jones; O. Henry"
I can match all but the last name with

```
\w+.*?;
```

Is there a regular expression that will match all the names, including the last one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does it here:

```
\w+.*?(?:;|$)
```

Comment: I think I understand what ;|$ is for, but I don't get what the ?: is doing. Could you explain?

Comment: The `(?:...)` is a non-matching group. It won't show up via a `\<n>` backreference.

Comment: No. `$` in a range matches a literal `$`, not the end of the line.

Comment: That's a **non-capturing** group, not *non-matching*. http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Answer (score 4):

don't have to use regex. it seems like between your names ,you have ";" as delimiter, so use that to split on the string. eg Python

```
>>> mystring = "J. Smith; B. Jones; O. Henry"
>>> mystring.split(";")
['J. Smith', ' B. Jones', ' O. Henry']
```

Comment: +1 for keeping it simple. I think the OP wanted all three names, so just `mystring.split(';')` would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

This is simple enough if you want a regex:

```
\w[^;]+
```

Perl example:

```
@names = "J. Smith; B. Jones; O. Henry" =~ /\w[^;]+/g;
# ("J. Smith","B. Jones","O. Henry")
```

Or if you want a split I'd use `\s*;\s*` (`\s*` to remove the spaces):

```
@names = split /\s*;\s*/, "J. Smith; B. Jones; O. Henry";
# ("J. Smith","B. Jones","O. Henry")
```